# How Do I Generate RowId For Intermediate Group Rows?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am working on implementing grouping w/ the Server Side Row Model. I need to generate an appropriate ID for the intermediate group rows. For example, if I group by Status then I would have intermediate rows representing each Status (NEW, IN PROGRESS, COMPLETE, etc). I need to come up with a unique ID for these rows (but preferable something deterministic if they need to be accessed/updated later).

The getRowId function is passed an object that contains things like the row's data, the previous parent group values, a reference to the api, etc.

What I would ideally like to know is the current list of group `fields`... I have all of the values readily accessible, but I don't know what field the current row is being grouped by - else I could just go grab that field from the row's data to use as part of the row id...

Is there any good way to acquire this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columnApi exposes the 'getRowGroupColumns' function from which the field property can be deduced:

```
getRowId: ({ columnApi, data, level, parentKeys = [] }) => {
  const groupColumns = columnApi.getRowGroupColumns();
  if (groupColumns.length > level) {
    const field = groupColumns[level].getColDef().field;
    return [...parentKeys, data[field]].join('-');
  }
  return [...parentKeys, data.athlete, data.year];
},
```